# Need only myself to be able to view the ribbon - but I do not have access to the Master Page to be able to use Security Trimming

Tags: permissions, ribbon, cewp

I only need to do this for one page on the site. I need to hide the ribbon so that only I can see it.

I cannot access the Master Page, so was hoping there was some script that could be added to a CEWP that would help me achieve this.

If I cannot hide the ribbon then I need to be able to grey out all buttons relating to lists e.g. I need the visitors to not be able to change the current list view.

I am using SharePoint 2010.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint StackExchange :) , Could you please take a quick tour at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tour to get informed badge! Thank you for your contribution !

Answer (score 2):

In case you need to hide the ribbon for one page, try to do the following:

- Using browser, Edit your page.
- Add  CEWP.
- Add the below CSS

  ```
  <style type="text/css">
  #s4-ribbonrow { display: none !important; }
  </style>
  ```

For more details check [HOW TO HIDE RIBBON IN SHAREPOINT 2010 USING CSS](https://blog.devoworx.net/2012/12/27/how-to-hide-ribbon-in-sharepoint-2010-using-css/)

Comment: Hello, thanks for that. How will I then check in the page when the script has been added into the CEWP?